# Xubuntu or Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu

Here's the thing. I forgot which I installed. I have used `cat /etc/lsb-release` and `lsb_release -a` and they both display Ubuntu 11.10. Well that's fine but Xubuntu and Ubuntu are pretty much the same thing so I wouldn't be surprised if they just used the Ubuntu as alias for Xubuntu. How can I make absolute certain which one I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Unity?

[image]

If so, that's Ubuntu. If not, that's Xubuntu.

Comment: Excellent. It's Xubuntu, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-desktop

uname -a

cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg  | grep menuentry

Comment: `uname -a` did not help. Rest of the commands did well.